# How to get current Appointment from RadScheduleView

Tags: telerik, radscheduleview

I have a Telerik:RadScheduleView control in a Silverlight application. When a user passes the mouse over an appointment item, I want to capture that appointment and call an event passing that appointment.

How can I capture the appointment that the user mouses over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AppointmentSelectionBehavior property of the RadScheduleView. For more detail...
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radscheduleview-features-appointment-selection-behavior.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use ScheduleVw.CurrentAppointment.This holds the current appointment the user is working on .Where ScheduleVw is your Radscheduleview

Comment: please format the code to make it better readable (select and ctrl-k will do the trick :-)